# Ubuntu desktop - Audio skips on Raspberry Pi 4

Tags: sound, raspberrypi

On a Raspberry Pi 4 running either Ubuntu 20.10 64 bit or Ubuntu Mate 20.04 64 bit, I have had the same issue with audio. In each case I have the Pi connected to a TV via HDMI and that is my audio connection.

While watching a video, the audio periodically drops out for approx 3 seconds and then comes back. This happens maybe once every couple of minutes, sometimes more frequently than other times.

The problem occurs less if I reduce the load on the Pi by reducing the number of open browser tabs.

I'm certainly not making the Pi busy but syslog reveals it keeps itself pretty busy chasing its own tail.

/var/log/syslog

contains vast numbers of entries referring to "tracker-extract.service"

A couple of favourites are:

tracker-extract.service: Failed with result 'signal'

tracker-extract.service: Start request repeated too quickly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer, upgrade from Ubuntu 20.10 to 21.04.

Don't make the mistake of thinking the solution has anything to do with 21.04's use of Wayland. Due to a problematic combination of Wayland, Raspberry Pi and a Logitech wireless keyboard, I'm forced to continue with Xorg.